# Métodos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, estoy comenzando a aprender JavaScript y me preguntaba por qué hay ciertos métodos como parseInt() en los que a lo que quieres afectar se mete entre los paréntesis, en cambio otros como toFixed() se ponen después del elemento con un punto. Mi ejemplo sería este:

```
var y = parseFloat(prompt("Introduce un número para pasarlo a 4 decimales"));

alert(y.toFixed(4));
```

Lo que quisiera saber es de que manera actúa cada tipo y como saber cuales se usan de cada forma. Gracias.

Comment: Hola amigo, te recomiendo que leas el manual de javascript http://www.manualdejavascript.com/section/manualdejavascript/

Answer (score 3):

Técnicamente en Javascript hay funciones, que se pueden llamar de diferentes maneras:

```js
function escribe(param) {
   'use strict';
   console.log(param);
   if (this) {
     console.log('Mi contexto es ' + this);
   }
}


let variableFn=escribe;

escribe('Hola');

variableFn('Hola de nuevo');

let objeto= new String('Objeto String');

objeto.metodo=escribe;

objeto.metodo('Saludos');
```

Si la función está asignada a un objeto, entonces es un **método** y el contexto será el objeto. En otro caso, el contexto será nulo (en el caso en el que declaremos nuestro código como "estricto", que es lo aconsejable).

En el ejemplo que has puesto, parseInt o parseFloat son funciones que reciben parámetros y devuelven valores en función de dichos parámetros.

En cambio, to Fixed es un método asociado al objeto `y`, por lo que `this` (el contexto) es `y` y lo que hace es devolver un valor que depende tanto del estado del objeto como de los parámetros de entrada. Básicamente puedes considerar que una función llamada como un método tiene un parámetro extra (`this`).

Hay muchos detalles que quedan fuera de esta explicación, pero conforme aprendas este lenguaje los irás descubriendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha servido mucho. Antes pensaba que eran métodos y no funciones predefinidas en JavaScript.

Comment: @SamuelReyes Por favor, si te han sido útiles, marca alguna de las respuestas como "aceptada" para que la pregunta quede como respondida

Answer (score 1):

Buenas:
Te recomiendo que prestes atención a la indicación de Pablo Lozano.
Sólo para responder a tu pregunta:
parseInt() es una función ya creada dentro de las especificaciones del lenguaje. Como es una función, se la llama indicando su nombre seguido de ( ) para que se ejecute. Las hay que lleven parámetros o no. Para eso utilizamos el enlace del manual que te han pasado.

toFixed() es un método del objeto Number. Al ser un método de un objeto, se usa indicando el objeto seguido de . y el nombre del método. Es así porque se ejecuta sobre ESE objeto.

Espero que esta aclaración te sirva para hacer más liviano tu aprendizaje.
Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha servido mucho. Antes pensaba que eran métodos y no funciones predefinidas en JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que nos pusimos filosóficos te comento que además de la respuesta de Pablo Lozano, que es absolutamente correcta, tú también podrías *extender el prototipo* de un primitivo (como Number o String).

Por ejemplo

`String.prototype.parseFloat = function() {
    return parseFloat(this,10);
};`

Y entonces en vez de `y = parseFloat("100.5",10);` podrías hacer

`y = "100.548654".parseFloat();`

O también podrías añadirle el método `toFixed` directamente al primitivo `String`.

`String.prototype.toFixed = function(precision) {
    var flotante = parseFloat(this,10);
    return flotante.toFixed(precision);
};`

```js
String.prototype.parseFloat = function() {
    return parseFloat(this,10);
};


y = "100.5".parseFloat();

console.log('y es ',y);


String.prototype.toFixed = function(precision) {
    var flotante = parseFloat(this,10);
    return flotante.toFixed(precision);
};

x = "100.456789".toFixed(3);

console.log('x es ', x);
```

Ahora, por qué hay funciones puras por un lado y en cambio hay métodos adosados al primitivo por otro lado? Eso es parte de los grandes misterios de la naturaleza y se debe más que nada a que JS partió como un lenguaje de scripting muy rudimentario y fue robusteciéndose y enriqueciéndose de manera semiorgánica con los años.

Por otro lado, extender el prototipo de los primitivos puede llevar a resultados inesperados. Puedes sobreescribir un método existente sin querer, o bien puede que tu proyecto utilice una librería que de por sí ya sobreescribe el prototipo de un primitivo, de manera que no podrás usarla en conjunto con tu proyecto.

Finalmente, hay paradigmas de programación (y esto no es exclusivo de JS) y en algunos, específicamente en la `programación funcional`, se apunta a tratar a toda variable como inmutable, y de obtener nuevas variables a partir de funciones que no alteren los operandos. De este modo, entre otras cosas, ningún objeto cambia de estado en el flujo de un programa y eso facilita el desarrollo basado en pruebas (TDD).

Por otro lado, también hay escuelas más pragmáticas que prefieren usar metaprogramación y escribir menos código haciendo que un objeto cambie sus propios atributos mediante sus métodos de instancia, o que se instancie a sí mismo si se lo trata como una función estática, o que exponga fachadas (`facades`) que simulen actuar como un método estático pero en realidad operen sobre un objeto autoinstanciado.

No explico todo esto para asustar a nadie. Es sólo para mostrar que JS tiene conceptos inconsecuentes en su mismo origen (`parseFloat` vs `Number.prototype.toFixed`) que simplemente son lo que son, pero si raspas un poco debajo de la superficie puedes llegar a encontrarte con niveles de complejidad infinitos sólo porque hay gente que le gusta rizar el rizo.